# dojox CheckedMultiSelect get checked value returns undefine

Tags: dojo

Please see below for the example. Console logs an array with "undefined" objects when checking the items from the dropdown. What is the correct way to get an array of checked items?
http://jsfiddle.net/4L3sksmt/4/

```js
require(['dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect'],function(CheckedMultiSelect){
var groupCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
      id: "groupChkMultiSelect",
      dropDown: true,
      multiple: true,
      label: "Group", 
      onChange: function(evt){
       console.log(evt);//output = undefined
      }
  }, 'GroupDiv');
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'One'});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Two'});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Three'});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Four'});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Five'});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.startup();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undefined` values are returned because you are not setting the value for the options. The correct format for options are `{ label : 'One', value: 1 }`. Below code should be working now.

```js
require(['dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect'],function(CheckedMultiSelect){
var groupCheckedMultiSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect ({
      id: "groupChkMultiSelect",
      dropDown: true,
      multiple: true,
      label: "Group", 
      onChange: function(evt){
       console.log(evt);//output = undefined
      }
  }, 'GroupDiv');
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'One', value: 1});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Two', value: 2});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Three', value: 3});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Four', value: 4});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.addOption({'label':'Five', value: 5});
 groupCheckedMultiSelect.startup();
});
```

Comment: Worked! Appreciate your help!